# Name for idea that if a concept is confusing you then you are starting to understand it

Tags: terminology

I feel like I've heard a term for this concept before, perhaps in the form of "(Person)'s Law"...

The notion that, only if a person finds a given concept bizarre/confusing/paradoxical are they really starting to understand it.

Examples of concepts that this can apply to: quantum physics, relativity...

Comment: That was my first thought. They referred me here

Comment: Yes, I've met this before too. Let's see who can recall it quicker!

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica: Epiphany? Eureka moment? (there may be duplicates...)

Comment: @Decapitated Soul -  Epiphany is what comes after. This is the state of confusion that precedes the final epiphany.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica is on the right path. This is the idea that certain concepts are just always counter-intuitive and as you look closer they can get more confusing

Comment: The 'learning curve'?

Comment: It's interesting that there seem to be a lot of words and phrases for the converse, where you don't understand something but think it's easy, but very few for this meaning. I wonder if it's in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases

Comment: My favourite for the 'converse' originated with The Irish question: "Anyone who says he has an answer doesn't really understand the question." // "According to Douglas Adams’ book the answer to all the ultimate questions of life, the universe, and everything else, is simply 42. Unfortunately, reality isn’t so uncomplicated. Many experts have compiled significant research on how the universe began, how it works, and  ...

Comment: what it is. It appears to be a never ending story. The more we learn about the universe, the more questions arise. Experts such as Albert Einstein ('the more I learn, the more I realize how much I don’t know'), and Socrates ('I know that I know nothing') have pointed this out. There is one thing we do know: our world is getting more complicated all the time." [[The Amsterdam Marketing Student](https://maamarketingblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/29/the-more-we-learn-the-less-we-know-does-expertise-even-exist/#:~:text=The%20more%20we%20learn%20about,nothing%E2%80%9D%20have%20pointed%20this%20out.)]

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting philosophical question.

I'm not sure if this is super helpful, but it reminded me of Bloom's taxonomy. As you ascend the learning hierarchy, you sometimes find you have more questions, but that really serves to prove you are gaining a deeper understanding of the subject.

It's not a single term, but it might explain the process you're describing.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom's_taxonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom%27s_taxonomy)

I also tend to say, "You don't know what you don't know." I use that when people ask, "If you didn't understand, why didn't you ask for clarification?" And I say, "Well, I didn't know that I didn't understand!" I guess it sounds like nonsense, but sort of implies that you only have real questions when you start to understand. Ignorance is bliss, as they say.

Answer (score 0):

**confusion /

the role of confusion in learning /

confusion accompanying cognitive disequilibrium**

This phenomenon has been studied. However, it does not appear to have a name other than *confusion*, its role in learning, or its association with *cognitive disequilibrium*. The earliest citations I've see in cursory look at the literature date to the work of the Swiss psychologist Jean Piaget in the 1950's.

As stated below, the idea is that confusion pushes you *reconcile discrepancies*. My understanding is that this is a process of continually separate/organize information into what is clear and what is not. Confusion lessens and, one hopes, disappears as the discrepancies become smaller and fewer.

> **Confusion** is a cognitive-affective state that occurs when a person is aware of an inconsistency between their knowledge and observed
> information and is actively seeking to reconcile the discrepancy.
> ...
>
> Thus, **confusion accompanies cognitive disequilibrium** which plays an
> important role in comprehension and learning processes (Piaget 1952;
> Graesser and Olde 2003). [S. D. Craig; "**Confusion’s** Impact on
> Learning"](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-1428-6_999) (2012)

> We tested key predictions of a theoretical model positing that
> **confusion, which accompanies a state of cognitive disequilibrium** that
> is triggered by contradictions, conflicts, anomalies, erroneous
> information, and other discrepant events, can be beneficial to
> learning if appropriately induced, regulated, and resolved. [Sidney
> D'Mello et al.; "**Confusion** can be beneficial for learning"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0959475212000357) (2014)

This is from a popular article about  D'Mello's work:

> "We have been investigating links between emotions and learning for
> almost a decade, and find that **confusion can be beneficial** to learning
> if appropriately regulated because **it can cause learners to process
> the material more deeply in order to resolve their confusion,**" D'Mello
> says. ["Confusion can be beneficial for learning" *Science Daily*](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2012/06/120620103233.htm)

I had a professor who said you shouldn't be discouraged and you're actually doing well when your studies reach a point where things start to become confused—this confusion will sort itself out. Of course the motivation to continue is key.